# Unexpected token Illegal

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to JS but I am required to use a bit. My IDE says this code is perfectly fine. However, the chrome developer tools is giving me this error. Being new and not that familiar with JS. I and pretty confused and lost. Could someone help me locate the error? and a quick fix?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 

[].forEach.call(
            document.querySelectorAll(#test1_test),
            setTimeout(
            function(htmlElement){
                htmlElement.focus();
                var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
                clickEvent.initEvent(type, true, true);
                window.qa_var = [];
                window.qa_omniture = [];
                htmlElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
            },3000)
        );
```

Comment: Look into JSLint or JSHint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll(#test1_test)
```

should be

```
document.querySelectorAll('#test1_test')
```

That selector is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the selector like this - `document.querySelectorAll("#test1_test")`